# Possible causes of BizTalk's WrongBodyPartException

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I keep getting **WrongBodyPartException Multi-part message 'msgWrapper' has body part 'Body', expected body part 'Head'** on one orchestration while another nearly identical one in the same application works fine.
[image]

I've debugged, redeployed, done many attempts until a colleague found a difference that's almost impossible to see. The bug is in the code generator for BizTalk orchestrations (see solution). First the description of the problem:

1. I defined two Multi-part Message Types, almost identical, but the Body part have different schemas. [image]
2. The orchestrations that use these Multi-part Message Types are almost identical, but not of interest to this problem.
3. Run both orchestrations. For me one was always working as expected, while the other one always suspended with the exception message above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was in my occasion that one of the Multi-part Message Types where created with Body part first and then Head, while the other one was created in the opposite direction. However that's completely hidden in the UI. There's no way you can see which order Body and Head are stored, because they always appear in the same order in the Orchestration View.
[image]

However if you manage to stop the messages that are working somehow, you can see the difference by inspecting message details and comparing the message part. This screenshot is showing both the failing situation to the left, and the working situation after a fix has been applied to the right:
[image]

To fix the bug, I had to open the .odx file of my Orchestration in XML view and move the message parts there. This is the comparison of the code change that fixed the problem:
[image]

The conclusion is that order of message parts is important, but impossible to see in the Orchestration View. It's hidden to the developer that there actually is a difference in order.

Comment: You are a hero - unbelievable! Many thanks!!!